# Do I Have a Memory Leak / Garbage Collection Bug?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm building an Air application, which, due to the workflow of the animators, needs to load a lot of external `swf` files.

I load them all via FileStream / Loader Objects at the boot process and then store them in an object for further use.

The instant they get loaded, I use a `gotoAndStop(1)` command to make them stop looping (the original files have no scripts whatsoever).

After the load process I can see the system memory go slowly but consistently up.
When I manually invoke Garbage Collection with the `System.gc()` command,
the memory gets cleared again.

If I let the application run for hours it seems the Garbage Collector does not run.

Any ideas what the problem might be? Or should I just forget about it and just occasionally run `System.gc()` manually?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should use memory profiler . If You cant , try adding 600x600 bitmapdata to instance and create code that initialize this instance, use and remove many times . Easy trick to see if instance is removed from memory. Also , read about ApplicationDomain , because each swf might sit in memory and loaded classes might not be removed.

Comment: System.gc() can only be run in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Garbage Collector will only run when it needs to, so it is entierly possible that it would go a very long time before running (especially if you have a lot of RAM available).

The important thing is the memory is cleared when it is run. This tells me that you don't have a leak, as it can be cleared up.

Also, how are you measuring the system memory? If you are doing it through Task Manager those numbers aren't really to be relied upon.

I recommend [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) . Monitor the 'Private Bytes' column instead.

Comment: Hello Alfie, 
thanks for the reply.
For measuring i use the System.totalMemory value of AIR itself.
On the MacOS side i use "top" in terminal.
Are there any Infos on when the Garbage Collector deems it worthy to get it's lazy ass out there ? ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Well really, the GC will usually just occur when it is full. A good approach (if you need to) is to call collection after a major state change in your application, and when any pauses/operation blocks won't cause user experience issues (for instance: loading a new level of a game). This looks like a good place to start for learning more: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/garbage-collection.html